# error time desync with timedatectl

Tags: sync, time

On server 18.04 I am having repeated sync errors detected by the small script and displayed here what is causing me big problems with some applications who has any idea of what can cause them? Thanks Andrea

```
ERRORE DATA -> api: "2018-10-15T13:18+02:00" server: "2018-10-15T14:21+02:00" timedatectl: Local time: lun 2018-10-15 13:18:02 CEST Universal time: lun 2018-10-15 11:18:02 UTC RTC time: lun 2018-10-15 11:18:02 Time zone: Europe/Rome (CEST, +0200) Network time on: yes NTP synchronized: no RTC in local TZ: no    
ERRORE DATA -> api: "2018-10-15T14:14+02:00" server: "2018-10-15T15:17+02:00" timedatectl: Local time: lun 2018-10-15 15:17:19 CEST Universal time: lun 2018-10-15 13:17:19 UTC RTC time: lun 2018-10-15 12:14:03 Time zone: Europe/Rome (CEST, +0200) Network time on: yes NTP synchronized: no RTC in local TZ: no    
ERRORE DATA -> api: "2018-10-15T14:14+02:00" server: "2018-10-15T15:17+02:00" timedatectl: Local time: lun 2018-10-15 15:17:49 CEST Universal time: lun 2018-10-15 13:17:49 UTC RTC time: lun 2018-10-15 12:14:33 Time zone: Europe/Rome (CEST, +0200) Network time on: yes NTP synchronized: no RTC in local TZ: no    
ERRORE DATA -> api: "2018-10-15T14:23+02:00" server: "2018-10-15T15:26+02:00" timedatectl: Local time: lun 2018-10-15 14:23:02 CEST Universal time: lun 2018-10-15 12:23:02 UTC RTC time: lun 2018-10-15 12:23:03 Time zone: Europe/Rome (CEST, +0200) Network time on: yes NTP synchronized: no RTC in local TZ: no    
ERRORE DATA -> api: "2018-10-15T14:24+02:00" server: "2018-10-15T15:27+02:00" timedatectl: Local time: lun 2018-10-15 14:24:03 CEST Universal time: lun 2018-10-15 12:24:03 UTC RTC time: lun 2018-10-15 12:24:03 Time zone: Europe/Rome (CEST, +0200) Network time on: yes NTP synchronized: no RTC in local TZ: no    
ERRORE DATA -> api: "2018-10-15T14:33+02:00" server: "2018-10-15T15:36+02:00" timedatectl: Local time: lun 2018-10-15 14:33:02 CEST Universal time: lun 2018-10-15 12:33:02 UTC RTC time: lun 2018-10-15 12:33:02 Time zone: Europe/Rome (CEST, +0200) Network time on: yes NTP synchronized: no RTC in local TZ: no
```

What can I do to fix this?